# htcaccess rewrite to subdirectory not working

Tags: php, apache, http, web

Some people might get angry and irritated once I asked this question again but I can't really make it work after trying all answers I have found here and I'm a newbie at this stuff too. Anyway I have a domain (www.testco.sample.com) that I want to redirect to a sub directory (/var/www/html/start/index.html) so I modified the .htaccess and add the following lines below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ start/index.html [L]
```

However when restarting apache it does not use the rewrite rule. I even tried the code below but to no avail.

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
# Change example.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
# Change example.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

Can somebody explain how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: did you allow overrides in virtual host?

Comment: Yes I did its one of the first things Ive checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing but the solution to my problem is very very simple that I had to spent 4-6hours searching, troubleshooting,  for answers(sarcasm!). What solved my problem was a one liner

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /start/index.html
```

Thank you for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

use  `RewriteBase`

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
RewriteBase /foldername/
# Do not change this line.
RewriteEngine on
# Change example.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/
# Don't change the following two lines.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
# Change example.com to be your main domain again.
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Is there any difference if the server is Ubuntu? Maybe I'm missing something.